# Can you send email with Gmail API authenticated by Service Account in python?

Tags: python, gmail-api, send, service-accounts

I'm trying to find a way to send automated emails from a python CLI in Heroku. The code I have here returns a SENT message in the console after I run the script but no actual emails get sent.

```
import base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "creds.json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
    scopes=["http://mail.google.com/"],
    subject="authorisedemailaddress"
)

emailMsg = 'Congratulations!'
mimeMessage = MIMEMultipart()
mimeMessage['to'] = 'someuser@gmail.com'
mimeMessage['subject'] = 'Well Done!'
mimeMessage.attach(MIMEText(emailMsg, 'plain'))
raw_string = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(mimeMessage.as_bytes()).decode()

service_gmail = build("gmail", "v1", credentials=credentials)
message = service_gmail.users().messages().send(userId='me', body={'raw': 
raw_string}).execute()
print(message)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include any errors and the response from the send.   How do you know the message wasnt sent? did you check spam filter or trash maybe? how long did you wait?

Comment: Sorry! First post thanks for the feedback! I'll update this when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

You live and learn...

The answer to this particular riddle was the "Congratulations" and "Well done" messages... sent the emails straight to the spam!

This code is a working solution to this issue if anyone needs it. Just be more cautious with your messages than I was.

DC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).